# Twilio, Programmable Voice, Say: Settings for voice, language, and loop are ignored

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio, text-to-speech, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

Until April 5th, 2022, the following twiml.html, as a part of a Google Apps Script web app, worked fine:

```
<Response>
     <Say voice="alice" language="pl-PL" loop="2"><?=msg?></Say>
</Response>
```

However, since said date, the message text is read by a male voice as per the pronounciation rules of American English (Man, en-US), and only once (loop="1").
The Call SID log shows no error and even states that voice="alice" language="pl-PL" and loop="2" have been applied.

I already contacted the Twilio support but they still have not fixed the issue.
As far as I conclude from the call logs, the Twilio support do not even have given a call to the phone number in order to get their own impression.

Who else experienced anything like that with Twilio programmable voice?
Are there any suggestions, workarounds, or solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check using a tool like postman that the returned MIME type is text/xml. For more details, visit this link.

Twilio Understands MIME Types
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#twilio-understands-mime-types

Comment: Thank you. - Obviously, the issue's cause is this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228222115?pli=1) on the part of Google Apps Script.

Which workaround on the part of Twilio can be suggesteg?

Comment: It look like you have 3 MIME types to work with based on the docs, text/xml, application/xml, text/html which doesn’t seem to help based on the current issue with XML and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/mime-type. You may have to proxy the request through a Twilio Function or similar to rewrite the MIME type in the interim until they fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you. - I tried the following:

`function diru() {
 const VoiceResponse = twiliogas.TwimlResponse; 
 const response = new VoiceResponse();
 response.say({voice: 'alice', language: 'fr-FR'},
'Chapeau!');
 console.log(response.toString());
}`

Phone call, answer:
`"We are sorry. An application error has occured."`

Call log:

`Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8`

Error log:

`parserMessage "Error on line 1 of document : The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed."
ErrorCode "12100"`

How can I fix it?

Comment: This works, but you need a framework like Express to return the TwiML to Twilio.

`const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

function diru() {  

const response = new VoiceResponse();  
  
response.say({voice: 'alice', language: 'fr-FR'}, 'Chapeau!'); console.log(response.toString()); 

}

diru()`

for example: https://github.com/twilio/starter-node

Comment: I suppose that in my web app, the framework is the Google Apps Script library `twiliogas` (please refer to the code that I posted above).
Obviously, there is another bug, or said library is not sufficient.

Comment: It appears to b a 5 year old unmaintained 3rd party library, otherwise you could open an issue on that repo. Sorry, not much help I can offer there.

Comment: Looks like Google Apps Script have accepted that this is a reproducible bug (based on the issue from the first comment). Twilio expects XML served with a Content-Type of `application/xml` or `text/xml` (I wouldn't have thought that `text/html` was valid, since TwiML is not HTML) and the issue is on the side of Google Apps Script here. As Alan has suggested, you could proxy requests and change the Content-Type, but getting Google App Script sorted is the primary fix here.

Comment: My workaround for: 1) Making a call: `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/.../Calls.json` with `"Twiml"`. 2) Incoming call: `Message` that has to be read is passed via `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC.../IncomingPhoneNumbers/PN....json` to `"VoiceUrl": https://handler.twilio.com/twiml...?msg=Message"` (= URL of the `TwiML Bin` for `A call comes in`). In `Message`, some characters, e.g. spaces, have to be URL-encoded.